# How to set required inputs when parent div clicked in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I'm trying to set required input fields when parent div is active?

Only active div's inputs must be required. I'm trying to do this for form submit. I also try with jQuery but it didn't worked.

PS: In fact, I don't want to use any jQuery code if possible. 
 My codes as seen below:

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope) {

  $scope.aClick = function(event) {
    $('input').removeAttr("ng-required");
    $(event.target).attr("ng-required", false);
  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Controller">
  <form name="frm">

    <div ng-click="aClick($event)">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="name" ng-required="true">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Surname" ng-model="surname" ng-required="true">
    </div>

    <div ng-click="aClick($event)">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Age">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Gender">
    </div>

    <button ng-disabled="frm.$invalid">Send</button>




  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-required doesn't have to be hard coded to true or false. You can use a variable off the scope. Then you can set that variable to true or false depending on what div is active or any other condition you want to account for. Maybe something like this depending on what you are doing

```
<div ng-click="aClick($event)">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="name" ng-required="div1IsActive">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Surname" ng-model="surname" ng-required="div1IsActive">
</div>




  $scope.aClick = function(event) {
   $scope.div1IsActive = true; // or whatever
  };
```